# SQLCODE 433 SQLSTATE 42806 when running a DB2 procedure that generates insert statements

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, utl-file, sqlcode

I am trying to pull together a script that will run through a given schema and output all of the table data as insert statements.

I have tested the script on a couple of tables and has completed successfully so started to run it on the full schema and get a SQLCODE 433 SQLSTATE 42806 error.  SQLSTATE 42806 error looks like its when the variables are incompatible but the table it fails on looks like it completes successfully when I trigger the procedure with only that table specified in the SQL.

The table is made up of the following data types:

```
BIGINT NOT NULL,
INTEGER NOT NULL,
SMALLINT,
TIMESTAMP,
VARCHAR (255),
VARCHAR (255),
DATE,
DATE,
VARCHAR (1) DEFAULT 'Y',
VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
DATE,
BIGINT
```

I'm using UTL_FILE to write the insert statements to an output file and not sure whether I'm hitting a limit on what I can write out, but cannot see any restrictions from the documentation I'm reading online.

The code for the procedure is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CREATE_INSERTS
(
    IN in_schema VARCHAR(50),
    IN in_output_dir VARCHAR(100),
    IN in_output_file VARCHAR(100),
    OUT out_message VARCHAR(100)
)
LANGUAGE SQL

BEGIN


    DECLARE SQLCODE                 INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE SQLSTATE                CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
    DECLARE v_table_name            VARCHAR(128); 
    DECLARE c_datatype              CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '20000';     
    DECLARE c_no_output_dir         CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '99901';
    DECLARE c_no_output_file        CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '99902'; 
    DECLARE c_no_output_dir_file    CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '99903'; 
    DECLARE c_noselect_cols         CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '99904'; 
    DECLARE v_filehandle            UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
    DECLARE isOpen                  BOOLEAN;
    DECLARE v_dirAlias              VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT 'mydir';
    DECLARE v_filename              VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT 'myfile.sql';  
    DECLARE v_datSQL                VARCHAR(1000);  
    DECLARE v_Column_Name           VARCHAR(128);
    DECLARE v_Data_Type             VARCHAR(18);
    DECLARE v_FirstTimeFlg          INTEGER DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE v_dynSQL                VARCHAR(10000);
    DECLARE v_colstatement          VARCHAR(10000) DEFAULT ' ';
    DECLARE v_datstatement          VARCHAR(10000) DEFAULT ' ';
    DECLARE v_data                  VARCHAR(10000);
    DECLARE v_start_quotes          VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT '''''''''||';
    DECLARE v_end_quotes            VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT '||''''''''';
    DECLARE v_cur_statement         STATEMENT;
    DECLARE v_col_statement         STATEMENT;
    DECLARE v_table_statement       STATEMENT;
    DECLARE c_table                 CURSOR FOR v_table_statement;   
    DECLARE c_column                CURSOR FOR v_col_statement;
    DECLARE c_data                  CURSOR FOR v_cur_statement;

    -- Catch errors
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR c_no_output_dir_file
    SET out_message = 'There was no output directory or file specified';    

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR c_no_output_dir
    SET out_message = 'There was no output directory specified';

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR c_no_output_file
    SET out_message = 'There was no output file specified for the insert statements';  

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR c_noselect_cols
    SET out_message = 'There was no columns found in table: ' || v_table_name;       

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    SET out_message = 'Error, SQLSTATE : " '|| SQLSTATE ||'",SQLCODE=' || CHAR(SQLCODE);     

    -- Check if file and location has been provided before proceeding...
    IF in_output_dir IS NULL AND in_output_file IS NULL THEN
        SIGNAL c_no_output_dir_file;
    ELSEIF in_output_dir IS NULL THEN
        SIGNAL c_no_output_dir;
    ELSEIF in_output_file IS NULL THEN
        SIGNAL c_no_output_file;
    END IF;

    -- Open file
    CALL UTL_DIR.CREATE_OR_REPLACE_DIRECTORY(v_dirAlias, in_output_dir);
    SET v_filehandle = UTL_FILE.FOPEN(v_dirAlias, in_output_file, 'w');
    SET isOpen = UTL_FILE.IS_OPEN(v_filehandle);

    IF isOpen != TRUE THEN
        RETURN -1;
    END IF;

    SET v_datSQL =  'SELECT TABLE.NAME'
                    ||' FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES TABLE' 
                    ||' WHERE UPPER(TABLE.CREATOR) = UPPER(''' || in_schema || ''')'        
                    ||' AND TABLE.TYPE = ''T''';


    PREPARE v_table_statement from v_datSQL;
    OPEN c_table;
    FETCH c_table INTO v_table_name;

    WHILE (SQLSTATE = '00000') DO   

        CALL UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_filehandle, '-- #########################');
        CALL UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_filehandle, '-- #');
        CALL UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_filehandle, '-- # INSERT ' || v_table_name);
        CALL UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_filehandle, '-- #');
        CALL UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_filehandle, '-- #########################');

        SET v_datSQL = 'SELECT colname, typename FROM '
                        ||' syscat.columns'
                        ||' WHERE UPPER(TabName) = UPPER('''||v_table_name||''')'
                        ||' AND UPPER(TabSchema) = UPPER('''||in_schema||''')'
                        ||' ORDER BY colno';       

        PREPARE v_col_statement from v_datSQL;
        OPEN c_column;
        FETCH c_column INTO v_Column_Name, v_Data_Type;

        WHILE (SQLSTATE = '00000') DO

            IF v_FirstTimeFlg = 1 THEN
                SET v_colstatement = v_column_name ;
                SET v_FirstTimeFlg  = 2;
            ELSE
                SET v_colstatement = v_colstatement || ' ,' || v_column_name ;
            END IF;

            FETCH c_column INTO v_Column_Name, v_Data_Type;
        END while;

        IF v_FirstTimeFlg = 1 THEN 
            SIGNAL c_noselect_cols;
        END IF;

        CLOSE c_column;

        SET v_FirstTimeFlg = 1;

        OPEN c_column;
        FETCH c_column INTO v_Column_Name, v_Data_Type;

        WHILE (SQLSTATE = '00000') DO
            IF v_Data_Type NOT IN ('BIGINT', 'INTEGER', 'DECIMAL', 'SMALLINT', 'CHARACTER','VARCHAR', 'BLOB', 'CLOB', 'DATE','TIME','TIMESTAMP') THEN
                SIGNAL c_datatype;
            END IF;

            IF v_Data_Type NOT IN ('BLOB', 'CLOB') THEN

                IF v_FirstTimeFlg = 1 THEN
                    SET v_datstatement = v_datstatement ||
                        CASE v_Data_Type
                            WHEN 'BIGINT' THEN 'coalesce(RTRIM(CHAR('||v_Column_Name||')),''NULL'')'
                            WHEN 'INTEGER' THEN 'coalesce(RTRIM(CHAR('||v_Column_Name||')),''NULL'')'
                            WHEN 'DECIMAL' THEN 'coalesce(RTRIM(CHAR('||v_Column_Name||')),''NULL'')'
                            WHEN 'SMALLINT'  THEN 'coalesce(RTRIM(CHAR('||v_Column_Name||')),''NULL'')'
                            WHEN 'CHARACTER' THEN 'coalesce(' ||v_start_quotes ||v_Column_Name|| v_end_quotes ||',''NULL'')' 
                            WHEN 'VARCHAR' THEN   'coalesce(' ||v_start_quotes ||v_Column_Name|| v_end_quotes ||',''NULL'')' 
                            WHEN 'BLOB' THEN   'coalesce(' ||v_start_quotes ||v_Column_Name|| v_end_quotes ||',''NULL'')' 
                            WHEN 'CLOB' THEN   'coalesce(' ||v_start_quotes ||v_Column_Name|| v_end_quotes ||',''NULL'')' 
                            WHEN 'DATE' THEN 'coalesce(' ||v_start_quotes || 'RTRIM(CHAR('||v_Column_Name ||'))'|| v_end_quotes||',''NULL'')'
                            WHEN 'TIME' THEN 'coalesce(' ||v_start_quotes || 'RTRIM(CHAR('||v_Column_Name ||'))'|| v_end_quotes||',''NULL'')'
                            WHEN 'TIMESTAMP' THEN 'coalesce(' ||v_start_quotes || 'RTRIM(CHAR('||v_Column_Name ||'))'|| v_end_quotes||',''NULL'')'
                            ELSE CHR(9) -- this will never happen
                        END;

                        SET v_FirstTimeFlg  = 2;
                ELSE

                    SET v_datstatement = v_datstatement || ' || '' , '' || ' || 
                        CASE v_Data_Type
                            WHEN 'BIGINT' THEN 'coalesce(RTRIM(CHAR('||v_Column_Name||')),''NULL'')'
                            WHEN 'INTEGER' THEN 'coalesce(RTRIM(CHAR('||v_Column_Name||')),''NULL'')'
                            WHEN 'DECIMAL' THEN 'coalesce(RTRIM(CHAR('||v_Column_Name||')),''NULL'')'
                            WHEN 'SMALLINT'  THEN 'coalesce(RTRIM(CHAR('||v_Column_Name||')),''NULL'')'
                            WHEN 'CHARACTER' THEN 'coalesce(' ||v_start_quotes ||v_Column_Name|| v_end_quotes ||',''NULL'')' 
                            WHEN 'VARCHAR' THEN 'coalesce(' ||v_start_quotes ||v_Column_Name|| v_end_quotes ||',''NULL'')' 
                            WHEN 'BLOB' THEN 'coalesce(' ||v_start_quotes ||v_Column_Name|| v_end_quotes ||',''NULL'')' 
                            WHEN 'CLOB' THEN 'coalesce(' ||v_start_quotes ||v_Column_Name|| v_end_quotes ||',''NULL'')' 
                            WHEN 'DATE' THEN 'coalesce(' ||v_start_quotes || 'RTRIM(CHAR('||v_Column_Name ||'))'|| v_end_quotes||',''NULL'')'
                            WHEN 'TIME' THEN 'coalesce(' ||v_start_quotes || 'RTRIM(CHAR('||v_Column_Name ||'))'|| v_end_quotes||',''NULL'')'
                            WHEN 'TIMESTAMP' THEN 'coalesce(' ||v_start_quotes || 'RTRIM(CHAR('||v_Column_Name ||'))'|| v_end_quotes||',''NULL'')'
                            ELSE CHR(9) -- this will never happen
                        END;
                END IF;
            END IF;

            FETCH c_column INTO v_Column_Name, v_Data_Type;

        END while;

        CLOSE c_column;

        SET v_dynSQL = 'SELECT '||TRIM(v_datstatement)|| ' FROM ' || UPPER(TRIM(in_schema)) || '.' || UPPER(TRIM(v_table_name)) || ' ';

        PREPARE v_cur_statement from v_dynSQL;          
        OPEN c_data;
        FETCH c_data INTO v_data;

        WHILE (SQLSTATE = '00000') DO

            CALL UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_filehandle,'INSERT INTO '|| UPPER(v_table_name) || ' ( '||v_colstatement|| ')  VALUES( ' || v_data ||');');

            FETCH c_data INTO v_data;
        END while;

        SET v_datstatement = '';
        SET v_dynSQL = '';

        CLOSE c_data;

        CALL UTL_FILE.NEW_LINE(v_filehandle, 2);

        FETCH c_table INTO v_table_name;

    END while;

    CLOSE c_table;

    CALL UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_filehandle); 

    SET out_message = 'Processing Success'; 

END
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: db2 provides this utility -- it is called db2look.  Why re-invent it?

Comment: Could you post the exact error message? SQL0433N is "value too long" and it should also give details regarding which value is meant

Comment: I thought db2look only outputs DDL to create the tables and views etc and did not output the data too.  What is the syntax to do this with db2look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it was a issue with FOPEN because the line was too big for the function.  To fix the issue, I used the overloaded FOPEN function and used the max size of 32767 and it generates the INSERT statements correctly into one file.

The final code is below in case its of any use:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CREATE_INSERTS
(
    IN in_schema VARCHAR(50),
    IN in_output_dir VARCHAR(100),
    IN in_output_file VARCHAR(100),
    OUT out_message VARCHAR(100)
)
LANGUAGE SQL

BEGIN


    DECLARE SQLCODE                 INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE SQLSTATE                CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
    DECLARE v_table_name            VARCHAR(128); 
    DECLARE c_datatype              CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '20000';     
    DECLARE c_no_output_dir         CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '99901';
    DECLARE c_no_output_file        CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '99902'; 
    DECLARE c_no_output_dir_file    CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '99903'; 
    DECLARE c_noselect_cols         CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '99904'; 
    DECLARE v_filehandle            UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
    DECLARE isOpen                  BOOLEAN;
    DECLARE v_dirAlias              VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT 'mydir';
    DECLARE v_filename              VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT 'myfile.sql';  
    DECLARE v_datSQL                VARCHAR(1000);  
    DECLARE v_Column_Name           VARCHAR(128);
    DECLARE v_Data_Type             VARCHAR(18);
    DECLARE v_FirstTimeFlg          INTEGER DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE v_dynSQL                VARCHAR(10000);
    DECLARE v_colstatement          VARCHAR(10000) DEFAULT ' ';
    DECLARE v_datstatement          VARCHAR(10000) DEFAULT ' ';
    DECLARE v_data                  VARCHAR(10000);
    DECLARE v_start_quotes          VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT '''''''''||';
    DECLARE v_end_quotes            VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT '||''''''''';
    DECLARE v_cur_statement         STATEMENT;
    DECLARE v_col_statement         STATEMENT;
    DECLARE v_table_statement       STATEMENT;
    DECLARE c_table                 CURSOR FOR v_table_statement;   
    DECLARE c_column                CURSOR FOR v_col_statement;
    DECLARE c_data                  CURSOR FOR v_cur_statement;

    -- Catch errors
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR c_no_output_dir_file
    SET out_message = 'There was no output directory or file specified';    

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR c_no_output_dir
    SET out_message = 'There was no output directory specified';

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR c_no_output_file
    SET out_message = 'There was no output file specified for the insert statements';  

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR c_noselect_cols
    SET out_message = 'There was no columns found in table: ' || v_table_name;       

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    SET out_message = 'Error, SQLSTATE : " '|| SQLSTATE ||'",SQLCODE=' || CHAR(SQLCODE);     

    -- Check if file and location has been provided before proceeding...
    IF in_output_dir IS NULL AND in_output_file IS NULL THEN
        SIGNAL c_no_output_dir_file;
    ELSEIF in_output_dir IS NULL THEN
        SIGNAL c_no_output_dir;
    ELSEIF in_output_file IS NULL THEN
        SIGNAL c_no_output_file;
    END IF;

    -- Open file
    CALL UTL_DIR.CREATE_OR_REPLACE_DIRECTORY(v_dirAlias, in_output_dir);
    SET v_filehandle = UTL_FILE.FOPEN(v_dirAlias, in_output_file, 'w', 32767);
    SET isOpen = UTL_FILE.IS_OPEN(v_filehandle);

    IF isOpen != TRUE THEN
        RETURN -1;
    END IF;

    SET v_datSQL =  'SELECT TABLE.NAME'
                    ||' FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES TABLE' 
                    ||' WHERE UPPER(TABLE.CREATOR) = UPPER(''' || in_schema || ''')'        
                    ||' AND TABLE.TYPE = ''T'''
                    ||' ORDER BY TABLE.NAME ASC'
                    ;


    PREPARE v_table_statement from v_datSQL;
    OPEN c_table;
    FETCH c_table INTO v_table_name;

    WHILE (SQLSTATE = '00000') DO   
        CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Processing table: ' || v_table_name);
        CALL UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_filehandle, '-- #########################');
        CALL UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_filehandle, '-- #');
        CALL UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_filehandle, '-- # INSERT ' || v_table_name);
        CALL UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_filehandle, '-- #');
        CALL UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_filehandle, '-- #########################');

        SET v_FirstTimeFlg = 1;

        SET v_datSQL = 'SELECT colname, typename FROM '
                        ||' syscat.columns'
                        ||' WHERE UPPER(TabName) = UPPER('''||v_table_name||''')'
                        ||' AND UPPER(TabSchema) = UPPER('''||in_schema||''')'
                        ||' ORDER BY colno';       

        PREPARE v_col_statement from v_datSQL;
        OPEN c_column;
        FETCH c_column INTO v_Column_Name, v_Data_Type;

        WHILE (SQLSTATE = '00000') DO

            IF v_FirstTimeFlg = 1 THEN
                SET v_colstatement = v_column_name ;
                SET v_FirstTimeFlg  = 2;
            ELSE
                SET v_colstatement = v_colstatement || ' ,' || v_column_name ;
            END IF;

            FETCH c_column INTO v_Column_Name, v_Data_Type;
        END while;

        IF v_FirstTimeFlg = 1 THEN 
            SIGNAL c_noselect_cols;
        END IF;

        CLOSE c_column;

        SET v_FirstTimeFlg = 1;

        OPEN c_column;
        FETCH c_column INTO v_Column_Name, v_Data_Type;

        WHILE (SQLSTATE = '00000') DO
            IF v_Data_Type NOT IN ('BIGINT', 'INTEGER', 'DOUBLE', 'DECIMAL', 'SMALLINT', 'CHARACTER', 'LONG VARCHAR', 'VARCHAR', 'BLOB', 'CLOB', 'DATE','TIME','TIMESTAMP') THEN
                SIGNAL c_datatype;
            END IF;

            IF v_FirstTimeFlg = 1 THEN
                SET v_datstatement = v_datstatement ||
                    CASE v_Data_Type
                        WHEN 'BIGINT' THEN 'coalesce(RTRIM(CHAR('||v_Column_Name||')),''NULL'')'
                        WHEN 'INTEGER' THEN 'coalesce(RTRIM(CHAR('||v_Column_Name||')),''NULL'')'
                        WHEN 'DOUBLE' THEN 'coalesce(RTRIM(CHAR('||v_Column_Name||')),''NULL'')'
                        WHEN 'DECIMAL' THEN 'coalesce(RTRIM(CHAR('||v_Column_Name||')),''NULL'')'
                        WHEN 'SMALLINT'  THEN 'coalesce(RTRIM(CHAR('||v_Column_Name||')),''NULL'')'
                        WHEN 'CHARACTER' THEN 'coalesce(' ||v_start_quotes ||v_Column_Name|| v_end_quotes ||',''NULL'')' 
                        WHEN 'LONG VARCHAR' THEN   'coalesce(' ||v_start_quotes ||v_Column_Name|| v_end_quotes ||',''NULL'')' 
                        WHEN 'VARCHAR' THEN   'coalesce(' ||v_start_quotes ||v_Column_Name|| v_end_quotes ||',''NULL'')' 
                        WHEN 'BLOB' THEN   'coalesce(' ||v_start_quotes || 'CAST (' || v_Column_Name || ' AS VARCHAR(32000))' || v_end_quotes ||',''NULL'')' 
                        WHEN 'CLOB' THEN   'coalesce(' ||v_start_quotes || 'CAST (' || v_Column_Name || ' AS VARCHAR(32000))' || v_end_quotes ||',''NULL'')' 
                        WHEN 'DATE' THEN 'coalesce(' ||v_start_quotes || 'RTRIM(CHAR('||v_Column_Name ||'))'|| v_end_quotes||',''NULL'')'
                        WHEN 'TIME' THEN 'coalesce(' ||v_start_quotes || 'RTRIM(CHAR('||v_Column_Name ||'))'|| v_end_quotes||',''NULL'')'
                        WHEN 'TIMESTAMP' THEN 'coalesce(' ||v_start_quotes || 'RTRIM(CHAR('||v_Column_Name ||'))'|| v_end_quotes||',''NULL'')'
                        ELSE CHR(9) -- this will never happen
                    END;

                    SET v_FirstTimeFlg  = 2;
            ELSE

                SET v_datstatement = v_datstatement || ' || '' , '' || ' || 
                    CASE v_Data_Type
                        WHEN 'BIGINT' THEN 'coalesce(RTRIM(CHAR('||v_Column_Name||')),''NULL'')'
                        WHEN 'INTEGER' THEN 'coalesce(RTRIM(CHAR('||v_Column_Name||')),''NULL'')'
                        WHEN 'DOUBLE' THEN 'coalesce(RTRIM(CHAR('||v_Column_Name||')),''NULL'')'
                        WHEN 'DECIMAL' THEN 'coalesce(RTRIM(CHAR('||v_Column_Name||')),''NULL'')'
                        WHEN 'SMALLINT'  THEN 'coalesce(RTRIM(CHAR('||v_Column_Name||')),''NULL'')'
                        WHEN 'CHARACTER' THEN 'coalesce(' ||v_start_quotes ||v_Column_Name|| v_end_quotes ||',''NULL'')' 
                        WHEN 'LONG VARCHAR' THEN 'coalesce(' ||v_start_quotes ||v_Column_Name|| v_end_quotes ||',''NULL'')'                             
                        WHEN 'VARCHAR' THEN 'coalesce(' ||v_start_quotes ||v_Column_Name|| v_end_quotes ||',''NULL'')' 
                        WHEN 'BLOB' THEN 'coalesce(' ||v_start_quotes || 'CAST (' || v_Column_Name  || ' AS VARCHAR(32000))' || v_end_quotes ||',''NULL'')' 
                        WHEN 'CLOB' THEN 'coalesce(' ||v_start_quotes || 'CAST (' || v_Column_Name  || ' AS VARCHAR(32000))' || v_end_quotes ||',''NULL'')' 
                        WHEN 'DATE' THEN 'coalesce(' ||v_start_quotes || 'RTRIM(CHAR('||v_Column_Name ||'))'|| v_end_quotes||',''NULL'')'
                        WHEN 'TIME' THEN 'coalesce(' ||v_start_quotes || 'RTRIM(CHAR('||v_Column_Name ||'))'|| v_end_quotes||',''NULL'')'
                        WHEN 'TIMESTAMP' THEN 'coalesce(' ||v_start_quotes || 'RTRIM(CHAR('||v_Column_Name ||'))'|| v_end_quotes||',''NULL'')'                      ELSE CHR(9) -- this will never happen
                    END;
            END IF;

            FETCH c_column INTO v_Column_Name, v_Data_Type;

        END while;

        CLOSE c_column;

        SET v_dynSQL = 'SELECT '||TRIM(v_datstatement)|| ' FROM ' || UPPER(TRIM(in_schema)) || '.' || UPPER(TRIM(v_table_name)) || ' ';

        PREPARE v_cur_statement from v_dynSQL;          
        OPEN c_data;
        FETCH c_data INTO v_data;

        WHILE (SQLSTATE = '00000') DO

            CALL UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_filehandle,'INSERT INTO '|| UPPER(v_table_name) || ' ( '||v_colstatement|| ')  VALUES( ' || v_data ||');');

            FETCH c_data INTO v_data;
        END while;

        SET v_colstatement = '';
        SET v_datstatement = '';
        SET v_dynSQL = '';

        CLOSE c_data;

        CALL UTL_FILE.NEW_LINE(v_filehandle, 2);

        FETCH c_table INTO v_table_name;

    END while;

    CLOSE c_table;

    CALL UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_filehandle); 

    SET out_message = 'Processing Success'; 

END
```